# JQuery add values of a dropdown and and input number field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form which does a calculation. It gets the value of selected option from the **Component** and multiplied with number of units entered in the input number field.

I can't get to show the number of units in the table because all values I'm currently selecting are dropdowns.

```
    $('#calc input, #calc select').each( function (index) {
       var input = $(this);
    $(tr).insertBefore("#finalrow").append('<td class=row-'+ $(input).attr("id") + '>' + $(input).find('option:selected').text() + '</td>');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arzg9mz3/11/)

[image]

Does this need an if else statement to select values from both input select and input number values ? How this can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

here is what you want.

```
/*const componentFactor = $(tr).children(".row-component").text();*/
  const componentFactor = parseInt($('#component').val());
/*const units = $(tr).children(".row-units").text();*/
  const units = parseInt($('#units').val());
```

JSFIDDLE [here](https://jsfiddle.net/arzg9mz3/13/)

Please let me know if helps

Comment: This is what I wanted, but when this is implemented total value in the bottom row is not working.